# How to dynamically create columns from function arguments

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing a function and want to pass its arguments to create columns in the data frame.

For example;

```py
def whatever(datain, knots):
  knots_length = len(knots)
  knot_names = ["knot_" + str(num1) for num1 in range(1, knots_length+1)]

  datain = datain.withColumn("var"+knot_names[1], whatever.....)
```

by doing this, I don't see the final column "var_knot_1" was created. Do you know how to get this done correctly? Thanks a lot.

Comment: **Spark data-frames are immutable**. In other words, `datain` you have inside the function is not the same as `datain` you have outside your function. So you need to `return` it inside the function and allocate it to your original `datain`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the dataframe:

```
# Initialise dataframe
df = ...

def whatever(datain, knots):
  knots_length = len(knots)
  knot_names = ["knot_" + str(num1) for num1 in range(1, knots_length+1)]

  datain = datain.withColumn("var"+knot_names[1], whatever.....)
  return datain

df = whatever(df, knots)
```